# CLLocationManager is slow getting location, Swift

Tags: swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager, location-services

Im creating this app, and it needs to get the users location - its all working properly, the thing is, that the time from accepting the use of location services, to getting the actual location takes like 5 seconds - is this normal?
I've used other apps, where it goes much faster..

Here's what my code looks like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Ask for Location-Authorisation from the User.
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }

    mapView.delegate = self

}



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

    let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: locValue.latitude, longitude: locValue.longitude)

    self.centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("could not get location")
}
```

But the time from the application gets the location to put into the centerMapOnLocation-function, seems just to be quite long. What is to be expected, when getting a users location? I'm testing on a wifi connection, so I know its not because the internet is slow, or its a bad connection...

Anyone have an idea? :)

Best regards!

Comment: try setting the accuracy and use locationManager.startUpdatingLocation(). I do that, and get answer within a second (on the device).

Comment: Awesome! locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() did the trick! I swapped it with .requestLocation(), and now its working like a charm! Thanks @JensPeter - would like to give you the correct answer, but I cant as its a comment :/ write an answer, and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try setting the accuracy and use locationManager.startUpdatingLocation(). I do that, and get answer within a second (on the device).

Comment: But the purpose of requestLocation is to get the location just once. Else it keeps on. giving the location until its stopped, the result it that it drains the battery

Answer (score 8):

From the documentation of **requestLocation()**:

> This method returns immediately. Calling it causes the location manager to obtain a location fix **(which may take several seconds)** and call the delegate’s locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:) method with the result.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation)

So basically, everything is fine with your code, it's just how the framework is built.

Comment: In my experience, requestLocation() is considerably slower (2x-3x) to return a result compared to startUpdatingLocation()

Comment: Yes, in my experience, requestLocation() is also much slower than startUpdatingLocation(). I'm not sure why, but I think it has something to do with location accuracy. Maybe requestLocation is trying to be super accurate every time, while startUpdatingLocation is less accurate? I'm not sure...

Comment: requestLocation() is slow because it starts location services, finds location and when it finds it the location services are stoped. If you use startUpdatingLocation() your location is updated frequently (every N seconds) and also drains more battery because of this. So consider how you are using it. If you use startUpdatingLocation() then maybe stop it with stopUpdatingLocation() after you receive location...

Answer (score 3):

When initializing your location manager, add **startUpdatingLocation():**

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
 manager.delegate = self
 manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
 manager.requestLocation()
 manager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Without **startUpdatingLocation()** geo-location takes about 5 seconds, with it, the request executes nearly immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to delay the app's launch for the location manager, consider deploying two location managers (in the app delegate), tasking one with generating a location quickly and the other with generating a location accurately:

```
fastLoc.delegate = self
fastLoc.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
fastLoc.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
fastLoc.startUpdatingLocation()

bestLoc.delegate = self
bestLoc.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
bestLoc.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
bestLoc.requestLocation()
```

The combination of `3 km` accuracy with `startUpdatingLocation()` should return a location almost instantly, almost always before the root view controller is even ready to go. `bestLoc` manager is likely to return a location well after the user has launched the app but it will be very accurate.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    switch manager {
    case fastLoc:
        fastLoc.stopUpdatingLocation()
        deviceLocation = locations.last! // set property with fast loc
        
    case bestLoc:
        deviceLocation = locations.last! // overwrite property with best loc
    default:
        break
    }
}
```